# Post Tweet to Twitter Not Working

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcUxU9BMyAE) to learn how to post a tweet to Twitter account using PHP. I grab the [PHP he give in the video description](http://pastebin.com/3xAuYXVe) & add my Application & Access Token details inside the script.

This is [my code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11245942).

```
<?php
$the_tweet = 'hello';
// TWITTER API ==================
    $consumerKey    = 'qu...xF';
    $consumerSecret = 'it...hG';
    $oAuthToken     = '24...ub';
    $oAuthSecret     = 'oy...d2';

    include "OAuth.php";

    include "twitteroauth.php";

    $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

    if (isset($the_tweet)) {
        $tweetmsg = $the_tweet;
        $tweet->post('statuses/update',array('status' => $tweetmsg));
         echo "Your message has been sent to Twitter.";
    } else {
         echo "Your message has not been sent to Twitter.";
    }
    // END TWITTER API ==================
?>
```

The github repo for this script is [here](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) ('OAuth.php' and 'twitteroauth.php' files inside the 'twitteroauth' folder).

MY PROBLEM

When I run my code with localhost (using MAMP), the tweet successfully sent to my Twitter account.

But, when I put it on my web hosting account and run the code, the tweet not sent to my Twitter account even I still get the success message like below.

[image]

How to fix this problem? Why the tweet is not sent and only sent successfully in localhost mode?

This is my Application & Token Access details (it's same like in my code):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you debug that `$tweet->post` ? make it a variable and dump it, `$test = $tweet->post('statuses/update',array('status' => $tweetmsg)); var_dump($test);`

Comment: @MihaiIorga I get this http://pastebin.com/vDsTbZsj

Comment: But that status is already posted: [check this](https://twitter.com/sbpconfession/status/459249197569417217)

Comment: @MihaiIorga oh sorry. That's from my localhost. Ok. I just run the same code on my web hosting account and this is the message I get: NULL Your message has been sent to Twitter. So, what should I do now?

Comment: then you are doing something wrong ... check if you loaded libraries. ...

Comment: @MihaiIorga all libraries are loaded. That's why it is working well on localhost.